# Error when using classes and then calling on the class

Tags: python

I made a class as you can see here.

```
    class Player():
        def __init__(self, name, maxhealth, base_attack, gold, weapon, curweapon, healing_potions):
            player = Player('player', 100, 100, 5, 30, 'Normal Sword', 'Normal Sword', 0 )
            self.name = name
            self.maxhealth = maxhealth
            self.health = self.maxhealth
            self.base_attack = base_attack
            self.gold = gold
            self.weap = weapon
            self.curweapon = curweapon
            self.healing_potions = healing_potions
```

But then when I try and call on the healing_potions part like so

```
                    if question == '2':
                        player_in_diningroom = True
                        print("You enter the dining room")
                        print("")
                        print("You find a Potion Of healing on the table!")
                        print("")
                        healing_potions += 1
                        player_in_diningroom = False
```

Then it gives me this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Isaiah/Desktop/All of my programs/Role playing game.py", line 179, in 
    healing_potions += 1
NameError: name 'healing_potions' is not defined
PS C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\All of my programs>

Comment: Is your method parameter list starting with `self`? You haven't indicated where you've defined your code.

Comment: `self.healing_potions` if the function is inside the constructor. Otherwise it might be something like your_player_variable.healing_potion

Comment: Generally you only use instance fields from methods inside your class. Methods start with `self` as parameter within Python.

Comment: Could you give me a example with my code that I have here?

Comment: So when I call on healing_potions += 1, I would instead do self.healing_potions += 1?

Comment: I assume the `player = Player(...)` on the first line of `Player.__init__` belongs somewhere else? What you show now would lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you all! Everything helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you initialize a player object inside your player class. This causes infinite recurison where you constantly create a player instance infinitely.
You most likely need to create it outside of your class. I've added a method to the class so we can increase the health potions using a method belonging to the instance. This is generally the recommended practice.

```
#player class
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, maxhealth, base_attack, gold, weapon, curweapon, healing_potions):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = maxhealth
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.base_attack = base_attack
        self.gold = gold
        self.weap = weapon
        self.curweapon = curweapon
        self.healing_potions = healing_potions
    def increase_health_potions(self):
        self.healing_potions +=1
```

Then we initialize a player instance/object. I noticed you had one extra parameter in the instance you created, so I removed one to make it work

```
#create an instance called player
player = Player('player', 100, 100, 5, 'Normal Sword', 'Normal Sword', 0 )

question = '2'
if question == '2':
    player_in_diningroom = True
    print("You enter the dining room")
    print("")
    print("You find a Potion Of healing on the table!")
    print("")
    player.healing_potions += 1 #accesing and increasing variable belonging to instance
    player.increase_health_potions() #call method belonging to instance that increases the variable 
    player_in_diningroom = False

print(player.healing_potions)
```

Take a notice at

```
player.healing_potions += 1
```

You have to reference the player, that you want to increase the health potions at.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly!